# Laravel Eloquent : Get object from database using JSON column key

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, eloquent

I tried to use the following code to retrieve an entire subscription object from my subscription table using the testId column.
testId column is delclared as "json" type but in reality, the content of this column is an array with a single string as follow :

```
 ["51602a95-73d1-4c24-b3b3-eee288b427e4"]
```

I tried to get the subscription object with this code but ot doesn't work. How can i adpat this piece of code to get the subscription object by searching the value of testId into the array ?

```
function getSubscriptionByTestId($testId) {
   $subscription = Subscription::where('testId', $testId)->first();
   return $subscription;
}
```

Comment: It looks like Laravel 5.3 makes an attempt at allowing the querying of JSON columns using `->where("{column}->{value_or_index}", "{operator}", "{comparison});`, see https://mattstauffer.co/blog/new-json-column-where-and-update-syntax-in-laravel-5-3 for more details. Note if you're not on Laravel 5.3, a `DB::raw()` query is most likely your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the values are like `["51602a95-73d1-4c24-b3b3-eee288b427e4"]` depending on your database engine you could use:

```
$subscription = Subscription::where('testId','like', "%$testId%")->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following, using a raw query. I'm not yet sure how to handle this with Eloquent, but will investigate further.

```
    return DB::select(
      "SELECT * FROM subscription
      WHERE testId->\"$[0]\" = \"{$testId}\""        
    );
```